# cant add the banner Ads of the airpush new SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, airpush

i am trying to add this in my main.xml

```
   <com.jrlnv.qmais91534.AdView
   xmlns:ap="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/myAdView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   ap:animation="fade"
   ap:banner_type="inappad"
   ap:placementType="interstitial"
   ap:test_mode="false"
   ap:canShowMR="false"
   />
```

this is the banner ads from the new airpush SDK

but i got this errors

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'canShowMR' in package 'com.MKA'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'placementType' in package 'com.MKA'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'banner_type' in package 'com.MKA'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'animation' in package 'com.MKA'
    - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'test_mode' in package 'com.MKA'
```

any help

thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You also need to place the mraid_attrs.xml file into your app's res > values folder. This file is included within the SDK download.